# Missing lookup in the API?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm using JavaScript and the Dynamics API to fetch my entities, but for some reason fields of type `Lookup` does not get passed to the JavaScript. Simpler types ad single line, multiple line, number and such are all passed thru as they are fields of the entity, but not fields of the type `Lookup`.

My query looks like this:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open("GET",encodeURI(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.1/pss_servicetasks"), true);
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
```

This query returns all the entities with their fields (without the fields of type `Lookup`) of the type `pss_servicetasks`.

Is there a reason why I'm missing the lookups? It gets all the other fields in the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use $select to mention column names to fetch. For example - name & ownerid lookup like below.

```js
req.open("GET",encodeURI(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.1/pss_servicetasks?$select=name,_ownerid_value"), true);
```

I recommend you to use CRM REST Builder tool to construct queries.

Ref: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmcustomization/archive/2016/10/18/ms-crm-2016-web-api-operations-retrieve-single-or-multiple-records

Comment: Hello Arun! Im getting 400 bad request when I add the select to my query. I have a filter too: "/api/data/v8.1/pss_servicetasks?$select=pss_name&filter=_pss_incidentid_value eq " + id. It works without the select.

Comment: $ missing before filter. Did you download crm rest builder from internet?